# Run a sub _once_, _every time_ a sheet is activated

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

WHERE I AM NOW:
I am writing an add-in for Excel in VB.NET. I sub that is called by the "SheetActivate" event in all sheets.

PROBLEM:
But it is not called when I start a new workbook or when I open an existing workbook. In those cases it isn't called until I select another sheet in that workbook.

Question:
How can I make it so that my sub is called once every time a sheet is activated, including when I open or start a workbook? I am not sure that I have thought of all situations in my text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Workbook.open event :

[Workbook.Open Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242003%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

and Application.NewWorkbook Event

[Application.NewWorkbook Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242002%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems to work well when I call the sub from these three events